# Language of Palindrome-Prefixed Words

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, context-free, pumping-lemma

> Classify the language 
>   $L = \{xx^Rw\ \big|\ (|x| \geq 0\ \wedge |w|\gt 0)\ where\ x,w\in\Sigma^*\}$ 
>   as one of:
>
> 1. Regular but not Context-Free
> 2. Context-Free but not Regular
> 3. Decidable but not Context-Free
>
> Most generally, $\Sigma^*$ can be any regular language (say $(a+b)^*$).

My first thought is that it can't be regular because palindromes themselves are not regular but I'm unsure if it is context-free or not. My hunch is to attempt the pumping lemma for CFL's to show that it is not context-free and, if that works, try to show that $L$ is decidable.

However, this approach feels prone to confirmation bias so I'm seeking some intuition by observing one's thought process in approaching such problems.

Comment: Hint: think about _exactly_ what strings are in $L$. Not just, "Oh, it's strings that begin with a palindrome, followed by anything at all" but take, say, $\Sigma = \{a,b\}$, start listing the strings in $\Sigma^*$ in lexicographic order and, for each one, figure out whether it's in $L$ or not. See if you can find a pattern.

Comment: "My hunch is to attempt the pumping lemma" -- then do so! What happens when you try that?

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Your question is a very basic one. Since you [did 
not include much of an attempt to solve it on your own](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594), we have little to
work with. Let me direct you towards our 
[reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599)
which cover your problem in detail.
Please work through the related questions listed there, try to solve your 
problem again and edit to include your attempts along with the specific 
problems you encountered. Your question may then be reopened.
Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat surprisingly, the language is regular. The key idea here is that you aren't given a $x$ and a $w$, but rather you want all words that *can be expressed* as $xx^Rw$ for *some* $x, w$. The only constraints are that $|\,x\,|\ge 0$ and $|\,w\,|>0$.

**Hint** Since you have free choice of $x$, why not choose $x=\epsilon$, the empty string. Then what will $xx^rw$ have to be?